# Custom Data Annotations - Client side validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to make client side validation work with my custom Data Annotations, the problem I'm facing is that, whenever I have a NON-required entity and submit my request (leaving the NON-required field blank), the client side portion of my code kicks in and tries to validate white space!  How can I avoid that?
Meaning, if the user does not enter anything, then don't validate?

Thanks!

Client side code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailvalid", function (value, element, params) {
var regex = /^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/;
return regex.test(value);
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("emailvalid");
```

Server side code:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmailValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    private Regex Regex { get; set; }
    private string pattern {
        get {
            return @"^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$";
        }
    }

    public EmailValidAttribute(string errorMessage)
        : base(errorMessage)
    {
        this.Regex = new Regex(this.pattern);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);

        // automatically pass if value is null or empty. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert an empty value
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var m = Regex.Match(stringValue);

        // looking for an exact match, not just a search hit
        return (m.Success && (m.Index == 0) && (m.Length == stringValue.Length));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ValidationType = "emailvalid";
        rule.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just perform a simple validation before testing the regular expression?
The $.trim() method is to ignore trailing spaces (assuming you're using jQuery).
Something like

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailvalid", function (value, element, params) {
    if ($.trim(value) == '') return true;

    var regex = /^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/;
    return regex.test(value);
});
```

Comment: Had completely forgotten about such an awesome function, trim! Thanks man, works perfectly :)

Comment: If your target audience meets the browser requirements (IE9+), you can use the built-in `String.trim()` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule that specifies that the input is not required.

See the jQuery validation documentation for more details: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules

You will have something like this:

```
$( "#myinput" ).rules( "add", {
    required: false
});
```

You can also return `true` in your validation if the input is whitespace, but since you're already using the validation API you might as well use its built-in features.

Comment: You are using a jquery selector, how would this be translated into my code? I do not want it to be tightly coupled to just ONE element, but I want to define the rule in general for all entities of type email

``

Comment: There is a conceptual difference between saying "an empty string is a valid e-mail" and "an empty string is not a valid e-mail, but this field is not required". I prefer to keep those two concepts separated, but if you're never ever going to require an e-mail I suppose that it's easier to include it in your validation indeed.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is it possible to define such a rule as the one you have posted using $.validator...?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could add a `not-required` class to your inputs and select them all like that.